# AngularJS - Init and load

Tags: javascript, load, angularjs, init

Is it possible to init a scope and ng-view in load?

**Problem:**
I have an AngularJS App with a list of Resellers. You can choose a reseller on a map and open details in a overlay-div (calling it with ng-show="show") on the route

```
when(
    '/dealer/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?19',
    controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl',
    activetab: 'details'}
).
```

The client wants now that when a customer opens the page, an initial details-overlay is open with the details.

**Solution (possible):**
Is it possible to, maybe ng-init, send the hardcoded :id of the chosen reseller to the controller and trigger the detail-overlay, so that it opens on load? Or maybe to trigger the route with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a default value for :id if not provided?

Best option is to have two `when` clauses in your `$routeProvider`:

```
$routeProvider.when(
    '/dealer', {
    templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?19',
    controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl',
    activetab: 'details'}
);
$routeProvider.when(
'/dealer/:id', {
templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?19',
controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl',
activetab: 'details'}
);
```

In your controller you can then assign a default value if not defined:

```
$scope.dealer = $routeParams.id || 'defaultDealerId';
```

Comment: Does this include that the overlay opens too?

Comment: normally, your ng-show should take care of it, but difficult to know without more code snippets